# T-SQL Null comparisons in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having a slight problem with a stored procedure in SQL Server. I am trying to select a phone number to get its `Id`, but I am having problems with the column `PhoneExtension` defined as an `int` and allowing nulls.

The following code works, but may not return the desired results (same phone number with multiple extensions may exist)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhoneNumberId]
    @phoneNumber INT,
    @phoneExtension INT = NULL,
    @countryCode INT = 1,
    @PhoneNumberId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @PhoneNumberId = (SELECT TOP 1 PhoneNumberId
                          FROM PhoneNumbers
                          WHERE PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber
                            AND PhoneCountryCode = @countryCode);
END
```

This next one does not work if `@phoneExtension` is `NULL` and the record in the `PhoneNumbers` table has `NULL` for `PhoneExtenstion`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhoneNumberId]
    @phoneNumber INT,
    @phoneExtension INT = NULL,
    @countryCode INT = 1,
    @PhoneNumberId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @PhoneNumberId = (SELECT TOP 1 PhoneNumberId
                          FROM PhoneNumbers
                          WHERE PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber
                            AND PhoneExtension = @phoneExtension
                            AND PhoneCountryCode = @countryCode);
END
```

Comment: use `PhoneExtension = @phoneExtension or @phoneExtension is null`

Comment: You could also you a `Case` statement. `PhoneExtension = CASE WHEN @phoneExtension IS NULL THEN PhoneExtension ELSE @phoneExtension END`

Comment: Not relevant to the Q you asked but `TOP 1` without `ORDER BY` means you could get any matching row - is this the desired result?

Comment: Won't that condition be true if '@phoneExtension' is null and PhoneExtension has a value (like 13) @VamsiPrabhala

Comment: @MartinSmith This procedure will be used on an INSERT statement to make sure that the record does not already exist before inserting a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhoneNumberId]
    @phoneNumber INT,
    @phoneExtension INT = NULL,
    @countryCode INT = 1,
    @PhoneNumberId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @PhoneNumberId = (SELECT TOP 1 PhoneNumberId
                          FROM PhoneNumbers
                          WHERE PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber
                            AND (ISNULL(PhoneExtension, '') = ISNULL(@phoneExtension, ''))
                            AND PhoneCountryCode = @countryCode);
END
```

Comment: Won't that condition be true if '@phoneExtension' is null and PhoneExtension has a value (such as 13)

Comment: No, in that case, "PhoneExtension = @phoneExtension" means "13 = NULL " which is false, And "PhoneExtension is null" is also false because PhoneExtension = 13

Comment: Tried it the other way, where PhoneExtension is NULL and '@phoneExtension' is 1, it returns unwanted values.  It seams I need to go with "AND (PhoneExtension = '@phoneExtension' OR (PhoneExtension IS NULL AND '@phoneExtension' IS NULL)"

Comment: In that case, you can use this updated query, please look at the modified answer. I think this is simplest now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhoneNumberId]
    @phoneNumber INT,
    @phoneExtension INT = NULL,
    @countryCode INT = 1,
    @PhoneNumberId INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @PhoneNumberId = (SELECT TOP 1 PhoneNumberId
                          FROM PhoneNumbers
                          WHERE PhoneNumber = @phoneNumber
                            AND (
                                PhoneExtension = @phoneExtension
                                OR 
                                (PhoneExtension IS NULL AND @phoneExtension IS NULL)
                                )
                            AND PhoneCountryCode = @countryCode);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
PhoneExtension = @phoneExtension
```

into

```
PhoneExtension = ISNULL(@phoneExtension, PhoneExtension)
```

When `@phoneExtension` is `NULL`, this filter condition will basically get ignored.